# How to resize image file in django model

Tags: django, python-3.x

**What I want:**

I have a *model* with an *ImageField* .  I would like to add a save method in the model to resize image before saving.

**What's going wrong:**

I got the code to work without throwing any error. But the image file was not resized.

I tried put the same code in views.py and uploaded images are resized correctly.  Wonder what I did wrong

**Environment Specifications:**
I am using *python 3.7* with *django 2.2*

**model.py**

```py
from django.conf import settings
from PIL import Image as Img
from PIL import ExifTags
from io import BytesIO
import os, shutil

class UploadFile(models.Model):
    image_file_path = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Img.MAX_IMAGE_PIXELS = 933120000
        if self.image_file_path:
            image = Img.open(self.image_file_path)
            (width, height) = image.size
            print(width,height)
            if (800 / width < 800 / height):
                factor = 800 / height
            else:
                factor = 800 / width

            size = (int(width * factor), int(height * factor))
            resized_image = image.resize(size, Img.ANTIALIAS)
            image.close()
            file_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, str(self.image_file_path))
            resized_image.save(file_path,optimize=True,quality=95)
        return super(UploadFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Do you see in console `print(width,height)`? Show lines where you are using this model.

Comment: Yes, I printed out both before and after resize.  the last print is the file path whioch came out as expected.  So the problem seems to be in the save statement.  Should I shutil.delete the initial file before saving?

Comment: Try to move `super(UploadFile, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` *before* your image resizing code.

Comment: A clean solution to resize image before saving it can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68601732/12284224).