# Django model ImageField creates a nested folder each time it uploads file

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm sure I'm missing something silly, but I'm confused.

I have the following model for my profile:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default="default.jpg",
        upload_to="profile_pics/",
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(["jpeg", "jpg", "png"])],
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image:
            self.image = make_thumbnail(self.image, size=(200, 200))
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

But the `profile_pics` folder keep nesting, so my folder structure starts to look like this:

[image]

My variables in settings.py look normal, I believe:

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

I believe the issue with the nesting folder originates with my save method in my Profile class, specifically this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.image:
        self.image = make_thumbnail(self.image, size=(200, 200))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

which is triggered by my signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

Why is this nesting the folders?

I'm using the same save method on the blog post images and there the folders don't nest.

What am I missing?

P.S.: In case it helps, this is make_thumbnail:

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.core.files import File
from PIL import Image

def make_thumbnail(image, size=(600, 600)):
    im = Image.open(image)
    if im.format == "JPEG":
        im.convert("RGB")
        im.thumbnail(size)
        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        im.save(thumb_io, "JPEG", quality=85)
        image = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)
    else:
        im.convert("RGBA")
        im.thumbnail(size)
        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        im.save(thumb_io, "PNG", quality=85)
        image = File(thumb_io, name=image.name)
    return image
```

Edit:

I incidentally arrived to this solution which is avoiding the main issue, although I'm not sure how efficient it may be:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.image:
        self.image = make_thumbnail(self.image, size=(200, 200))
        image_name = self.image.name
        ext = image_name.split(".")[-1]
        filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
        clean_name = os.path.join("", filename)
        self.image.name = clean_name
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    else:
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Try after removing the slash from `profile_pics/` from `upload_to` option. i.e set `upload_to='profile_pics'`

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't change the behaviour. I believe this happens (this nesting) each time I login...

Comment: Did you try ‘blog_photos/profile_pics’ ?

Comment: No, changing the upload_to in the model doesn't solve it. I must be doing something wrong elsewhere but I don't really know where to look... Definitely a new nested folder is created each time I login

Comment: Could you show your login view?

Comment: the log in view is the default class view from django.contrib.auth, so there's no explicit view for login in my app.

(In urls.py: `auth_views.LoginView.as_view`)

Comment: You don't need `save_profile` signal. Try removing it.

Comment: I did, and that solves the resave on login, but the issue persists when the user wants to select a new image (avatar). So if the user decides to change his avatar, it's saved in a nested profile_pics inside profile_pics. If I remove the save method in the class, the images save correctly, but I'd like to resize them before.

Comment: And even if he just updates the username or email address, the avatar is resaved in a new nested folder. The only way to prevent this is by getting rid of the save method in the Profile class, but I'd like to resize the avatars, so maybe there's something wrong in it?

Comment: Could you show make_thumbnail function?

Comment: Also, if you want resize your image befor saving, check out this post answer about Django-resized library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111648/how-to-resize-an-imagefield-image-before-saving-it-in-python-django-model/57111737

Comment: I just updated my question with make_thumbnail, thank you. Maybe django-resized will produce the same nesting problem, after reading the answer from Tom below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet you wanted to adjust [this post](https://bhch.github.io/posts/2018/12/django-how-to-editmanipulate-uploaded-images-on-the-fly-before-saving/) to your needs. The author doesn't have a problem, because he's "not reusing what he is saving into".

`self.image` has attribute `name`. When you check if it exists (`if self.image`), it already has a name. Then with each update you keep resizing already resized image, which also keeps adding already existing image name to `upload_to` path, so with each iteration it does `upload_to` + `self.image.name`. But `self.image.name` is already `/profile_pics/...`.

To resolve this problem, just add `is_resized` column.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(
        default="default.jpg",
        upload_to="profile_pics/",
        validators=[FileExtensionValidator(["jpeg", "jpg", "png"])],
    )
    is_resized = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.image and not self.is_resized:
            self.is_resized = True
            self.image = make_thumbnail(self.image, size=(200, 200))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Just remember to set `is_resized` to `False` whenever the image changes.

Side note, signals in general are a bad practice. I also don't think it's a good idea to have two signals that operate on the same objects.

If you really need to have them, consider replacing them with a single signal.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def handle_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

Though it'd be better if you run resizing the thumbnail in your view.

Comment: Oh I can start to understand why the nesting! Amazing eye, thank you!
Just to be sure, where do I set is_resized to False again? Are we not running again in the same nesting when that happens?

Comment: Hi Tom. I came up with a way in my save method without adding an extra column to the table. I don't know if you would approve of it and I'd be glad to hear what you think. I pasted it at the end of my original question.

Comment: And perhaps I could have avoided all this by letting save the images in the media folder rather than in the "profile_pics/" from my upload_to...

Comment: Set `is_resized` to `False` whenever user changes his profile pic, so you need to check that with each PUT (or other) request in one of your views. There are other solutions without adding column, fe. `if not self.image.name.endswith('resized'): resize and add 'resized' to name`. Your solution is not valid as it will still resize with each `save()` which is definitely not something you want. Please accept the answer.

Comment: I'll take the word of an expert and will try and apply your method, Tom. Thank you very much, and hope I don't break something in the process :)

Comment: I don't seem to be able to make it work. After creating the column and adjusting the save method, I added this in the view: 
` if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            request.user.profile.is_resized = False`
And the user never hits the thumbnail function. Sorry if I sound dumb with this, just a bit lost as a beginner! (p.s. sorry I don't think it's possible to paste code in here. Apologies for that!)

Comment: I think this is working now: 
```if request.method == "POST":  if request.FILES:  request.user.profile.is_resized = False```

I hope I'm right!

Comment: That probably is correct! :) I think you only need to check for `request.FILES` because create is send with POST and update with PUT. But yes, that's the trick. good job

Comment: Although remember that you don't need to add `is_resized` column if you make a thumbnail right over there, `if request.FILES`. But that's out of the scope for this question.

Comment: You're right! Thank you so much, this helped me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

There is a thing in django called 'duplicate signals'. This occurs everywhere your project imports the module where you define the signals, because signal registration runs as many times as it is imported.

Maybe you can solve your problem by passing a unique identifier as the dispatch_uid argument to identify your receiver function.

```
from django.core.signals import request_finished

request_finished.connect(my_callback, dispatch_uid="my_unique_identifier")
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/

Comment: Thanks so much, but nevertheless this issue persists: why does it create a 'profile_pics" folder nested in the previous one? Even when I need to use the signal?

Comment: I'm stumped, especially since you say blog_photos behaves normally. Just, make sure that the file that originates the signal is encapsulted properly or not imported by any other modules when logging in.

Comment: Yes, I just triple checked and blog_photos behave well even though it uses the same function to reduce the image size (I just updated my question for more detail). I'm very confused...
When I delete the 'def save()' from the model, the images upload correctly (but of course they don't resize)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the "path" is already in the image URL.

```
if self.image:
    if "profile_pics/" not in self.image.url:
        self.image = make_thumbnail(self.image, size=(200, 200))
```